# org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: The assignment expression type sql.Timestamp did not match the assignment path type OffsetDateTime

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, h2, liquibase

I had the below Postgres query with Spring Boot version 2.x,

```
UPDATE TABLE SET lastDateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE x = :y
```

while running the integration test case using h2 data, the liquibase is configured with the below details

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 10
      author: auth01
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: TABLE
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: last_date_Time
                  type: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
```

When it is upgraded to Spring boot 3.x as per below

```
SPRING BOOT PARENT VERSION 3.1.3
hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final
org.postgresql:postgres:42.5.4
com.h2database:h2 : 2.2.224
io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62:3.5.3
```

> The error is org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: The assignment
> expression type [java.sql.Timestamp] did not match the assignment path
> type [java. time.OffsetDateTime] for the path
> [alias_1617001542.lastDateTime]
>
> I tried changing TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE to TIMESTAMP and to DATETIME
> and to TIMESTAMPZ in liquibase, but still no luck. Any suggestion is
> appreciated

.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-Boot 2 uses Hibernate 5. Spring-Boot 3 uses Hibernate 6.

There's a Hibernate 6 [migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html).

> Instant mapping changes
>
> Instant now maps to the type code SqlType.TIMESTAMP_UTC by default,
> which maps to the SQL type timestamp with time zone if possible, and
> falls back to timestamp. Due to this change, schema validation errors
> could occur on some databases.
>
> The migration to timestamp with time zone might require a migration
> expression like cast(old as timestamp with time zone).
>
> To retain backwards compatibility, configure the setting
> hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type to TIMESTAMP.

Try setting property `hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type=TIMESTAMP`